# Invoking a SOAP ( Web Services ) from ORACLE DB

Tags: java, web-services, oracle, class, plsql

Kindly note that I’m trying to invoke a SOAP (web services) from ORACLE DB using pl\sql , after I have done some investigations it says that I have to use the UTL_HTTP package  but It didn't work with me !!!

Kindly to advice me , where should I exactly place the following SOAP in pl\SQL  to be invoked .... is it posible ?

There are two SOAPs (1.1 nd 1.2 ) , both of any can work :

- SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values

POST /gmgwebservice/service.asmx HTTP/1.1 Host: 212.35.66.180 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: length SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SendSMS"                  string       string       string       string       string          HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: length                  string

**SOAP 1.2

The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /gmgwebservice/service.asmx HTTP/1.1 Host: 212.35.66.180 Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: length                  string       string       string       string       string          HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: length                  string

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "it didn't work with me !!!"

Comment: It didn't work with me means i couldn't invoke the Web service in my ORACLE codes .

Answer (score 0):

try checking out [Calling a SOAP web service from PL/SQL by extending the FLEX_WS_API](http://www.ora600.be/node/5975)

Answer (score 0):

check this out: [Ws on PL/SQL](http://frohikyoracle.blogspot.com/2008/12/consuming-web-services-using-plsql.html)